# Why does EVE try to shoot Billy Bass?

Tags: wall-e

In Wall-E's home, once Billy Bass starts singing, EVE points her gun at it. Since it's not living, it's harmless. Why does EVE try to shoot Billy Bass anyway?

Comment: I think the better question is why everyone with a gun doesn't immediately try to shoot Billy Bass.

Comment: @user144247  If Billy Bass is nonliving and also a non sentient machine as opposed to sentient machines like Wall-E, there would be nothing wrong with shooting it.  Thus it would perfectly correct and right to shoot it for the flimiest reason or no reason at all, the way some people shoot at bottles or tin cans.  If Billy Bass is a sentient robot like Wall-E shooting him without a good reason would be wrong.

Answer (score 10):

Wall-E is not living. She still tried to shoot him. *Several times*. [And that was just their first meeting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SDAX0eVSRc0).

At this time she is very "shoot first, then some more, never leave anything to ask questions to". She shoots or at least aims at any movement or noise source she detects.

Comment: +1 Living v. non-living isn't a big part of Eve's shooting criteria. She shoots Wall-E a few times, but doesn't shoot the insect when it isn't threatening.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the script](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Wall-E.html), she was "spooked" by it.

> She drifts through the sea of knickknacks.
> Becomes spooked by a SINGING BILLY BASS FISH.
> Threatens to shoot it, but Wall-E calms her down.

Note that her first reaction to *anything* that surprises her is [one of extreme defensiveness](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=20&v=L6cFeJQkntk&feature=youtu.be).